# How to get device name with D-Bus?

Tags: c++, linux, dbus, bluez, qtdbus

I develop an application in C++ on Linux, which interacts with blueooth devices (such as bluetooth sockets or speakers).
I use D-Bus command to get list of paired devices:

`dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply $BTADAPTER org.bluez.Adapter.ListDevices`

It returns:

```
method return sender=:1.0 -> dest=:1.90 reply_serial=2
   array [
      object path "/org/bluez/489/hci0/dev_00_1F_C5_75_45_5E"
      object path "/org/bluez/489/hci0/dev_F0_13_C3_00_A1_08"
      object path "/org/bluez/489/hci0/dev_00_11_12_30_76_21"
      object path "/org/bluez/489/hci0/dev_00_11_12_30_76_22"
      object path "/org/bluez/489/hci0/dev_00_11_12_30_76_23"
      object path "/org/bluez/489/hci0/dev_00_11_12_30_76_24"
   ]
```

It is great, but I need not only MACs, but names of devices also (e.g. "linvor" or "GT-I9300").

Please, help me with a proper way to get those names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.bluez "/org/bluez/489/hci0/dev_00_1F_C5_75_45_5E" org.bluez.Device.GetProperties , you will get all information about that device