# Ubunu, BlueZ, Enumerating paired devices

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

Using the BlueZ BlueTooth stack, How do I **programatiacally** enumerate devices that are already paired and not necessarily connected?

Answer (score 1):

*Update: The below wasn't as easy as I initially thought to be. `adapter_get_devices` is only the starting point. It will be helpful, if you could post a sample out of that.

If you don't have enough time, you can as well use the same [bt-device](http://code.google.com/p/bluez-tools/) tool from command line with appropriate command line params and get the output via pipe. Other choice is to use the `ListDevices` API in [org.bluez.Adapter](http://maemo.org/api_refs/5.0/beta/bluez/adapter.html) interface to get a list of paired devices and then I hope some thing in [org.bluez.Devices](http://maemo.org/api_refs/5.0/beta/bluez/device.html) interface will help you.

Update 2: In devices interface you can use, `GetProperties` method as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19290981/1180117)*

Does this gsoc [code sample link](https://github.com/rpicopter/bluez-tools/blob/master/src/bt-device.c#L318) help. It is in C now and hope it could be done over Python dbus as well. API is `adapter_get_devices`. I am yet to try this.